# Running npm create vite@latest project gives module error on macOS Catalina

Tags: vite

I can run this same command on Ubuntu or Windows and I get no issues.

```
import fs from 'node:fs'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Comment: What version of Node are you running?

Comment: Node version: v12.14.1

Comment: What is this "create" command even doing? I know it's install + init together or something but there is no official documentation at npmjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Node 12.14.1, which is not compatible with Vite 3.

From [Vite 3's docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project):

> #### Compatibility Note
>
> Vite requires [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) version >=14.18.0. However, some templates require a higher Node.js version to work, please upgrade if your package manager warns about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm create vite@latest my-vue-app -- --template vue
npm create vite@latest
npm create vite@latest my-vue-app --template vue
npm create vite@latest my-vue-app -- --template vue
yarn create vite my-vue-app --template vue
pnpm create vite my-vue-app --template vue
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Can you please explain **how** your code solves OP's issue? It seems an answer was already accepted which suggests a version issue.